# A set that is not polynomial time enumerable

Tags: polynomial-time, mathematical-foundations, one-way-functions

For a set $I\subseteq \Bbb N$, defined $s_{I}(n)=\min\{i\in I\mid i>n\}$. The set $I$ is called *polynomial-time-enumerable* if $s_I(n)$ is computable in $\mathsf{poly}(n)$ time.

Most of the sets I can imagine are polynomial time enumerable. I am really looking for an example of **a set of integers that is NOT polynomial time enumerable.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take any uncomputable set.

Comment: when is a set of integers uncomputable?

Comment: A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is undecidable if there is no Turing machine that on any input $n \in S$ halts, answering Yes, and on any input $n \notin S$ halts, answering No.